# Classification of closed subgroups of U(2)

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, unitary-matrices

Do we know a complete classification of all closed subgroups of $U(2)$.

1) upto isomorphism

2) upto conjugation

If so could someone provide me a reference as to where I might find this or some techniques as to how does one begin such a classification.The only ones I can see apriori are the usual $T^2$ (sitting as diagonal matrices) $S^1$ (sitting as (p,q) circles inside $T^2$) and the various groups that come from lifting subgroups of $SO(3)$ to $SU(2)$ under the usual covering map. I presume there should be a lot more but do we have some sort of classification in the literature?

Or if its easier to somehow classify just the abelian ones it would still be helpful is someone could point me to a source on this classification as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want *all* subgroups or just the closed ones? For example, for any $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, $H_\alpha := \{\operatorname{diag}(\exp(i \theta), \exp(i \alpha \theta))\} : \theta \in \Bbb R\}$ is a subgroup of $T^2 \subset U(2)$, but if (in fact, iff) $\alpha$ is irrational then $H_\alpha$ is not closed and its closure is $T^2$.

Comment: Just the closed ones. I've edited the question. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: IIRC it is known that all of the discrete subgroups of $SU(2)$ are lifts of those of $SO(3)$; the classification of the latter is a classic problem (which can be resolved using the so-called ADE classification).

Comment: This should be pretty doable using just the classification of discrete subgroups of $SU(2)$. You can organize the subgroups based on 1) their connected component at the identity (classifiable using subalgebras of the Lie algebra) and 2) their image under the determinant map to $U(1)$.